# Put a Button on first row of WPF DataGrid Columns

Tags: wpf, button, datagrid

I'm working on the WPF application.

My application has a DataGrid with 4 columns which works properly.

I only want the first row to have a Button with DataGrid width for inserting new data by user's click.

First row's columns may be use Column span.

Also I read [How to add button in first row of datagrid column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128494/how-to-add-button-in-first-row-of-datagrid-column) .
This solution Insert Button to All Rows and control with Collapsing .

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Take a look at the markup in the link you included. Add a setter in your style to set visibility collapsed by default. Use index = 0 as the condition in the trigger to set visibility visible.

Comment: two ways to do this. 1. use columnspan for the button as the first item. 2. edit datagrid's template and add the button there, the same way it's done it that link.

Comment: Thx alot @Andy & Bizhan . I try your advice .